# Converting distance in ArcGIS Android SDK?

Tags: android, arcgis-android

I have a Polyline that I draw on the map and I would like to get its distance in meters.

right now it's not working, basically what I have is

```
   distanceSeg=new Polyline();
   double  len1=distanceSeg.calculateLength2D();
   double m_len=
         Unit.convertUnits(len1,Unit.create(AngularUnit.Code.DEGREE),Unit.create(LinearUnit.Code.METER));
```

The call to Unit.convertUnits throws a GeometryException with "invalid_call".

Any ideas?

Comment: I think it's failing because the input/output unit 'types' are not the same. That is, not both angular nor linear (nor areas). The help doc for calculateLength2D does say that if the coordinate system is gcs, use geodesicLength from GeometryEngine as @Steve says in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not overly familiar with the Android API but I am wondering if GeometryEngine.geodesicLength might be an easier approach.

[GeometryEngine.geodesicLength javadoc](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/android-sdk/api/com/esri/core/geometry/GeometryEngine.html#geodesicLength%28com.esri.core.geometry.Geometry,%20com.esri.core.geometry.SpatialReference,%20com.esri.core.geometry.LinearUnit%29)

Comment: Thank you Steve, this indeed works, I had figured this out a while ago but forgot to edit the question, thank you!